# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/jms/MessageListener

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I am getting this problem when I am running my Java Class

```
public class DrawingApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        BeanFactory factory = new XmlBeanFactory(new FileSystemResource("spring.xml"));
        Triangle triangle = (Triangle)factory.getBean("triangle");

        triangle.draw();

    }
}
```

Comment: What is your stacktrace? Which line does it concern?

Comment: Please add some more details - full stacktrace for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guessing from the title of your question, it seems you are missing the `jms` dependency.

You should add [this jar](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.jms/jms/1.1) to your classpath (Java Message Service version 1.1). If you are using Maven, this dependency will do:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
    <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
</dependency>
```